mastering python data analysis textbook cumulative distribution code not working
I'm reading Mastering Python Data Analysis and I've come across some code from the textbook that doesn't seem to compile properly, I'm not the most familiar with Python so I haven't been able to figure out what's went wrong. The textbook shows code that is intended to be used to plot a cumulative distribution function, however it seems like when I call this function it throws an error. If anyone has some insights as to what may be going wrong, I'd appreciate the help in learning this.
my imports for this bit of code:
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

This is the function as shown in the textbook to plot the cumulative distribution (note, I've added the print statements to try and figure out where it's breaking):
# define a function that can plot cumulative distribution function (cdf)
def plot_cdf(data, plot_range=None, scale_to=None, **kwargs):
    print("inputs received: data: {}, plot range: {}, scale to: {}".format(data, plot_range, scale_to))
    num_bins = len(data)
    sorted_data = np.array(sorted(data), dtype=np.float64)
    data_range = sorted_data[-1] - sorted_data[0]
    counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(sorted_data, bins=num_bins)
    print("bin edges: {}".format(bin_edges))
    xvalues = bin_edges[:1]
    print("counts: {}, np.cumsum: {}".format(counts, np.cumsum(counts)))
    yvalues = np.cumsum(counts)
    if plot_range is None:
        xmin = sorted_data[0]
        xmax = sorted_data[-1]
    else:
        xmin, xmax = plot_range
    #pad the arrays
    xvalues = np.concatenate([[xmin, xvalues[0]], xvalues, [xmax]])
    yvalues = np.concatenate([[0.0, 0.0], yvalues, [yvalues.max()]])
    print("x values: {}".format(xvalues))
    print("y values: {}".format(yvalues))
    if scale_to is not None:
        yvalues = yvalues / len(data) * scale_to
    plt.axis([xmin, xmax, 0, yvalues.max()])
    return plt.plot(xvalues, yvalues, **kwargs)

This is the method shown by the textbook that causes the error:
xmin = 0
xmax = 3.5
xx = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,200)
plt.plot(xx, rvweib.cdf(xx), color='orange', lw=5)
plot_cdf(weib_variates, plot_range=[xmin, xmax], scale_to=1, lw=2, color='green')
plt.axis([xmin, xmax, 0, 1])
plt.title('Weibul distribution simulation', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('Failure Time', fontsize=12);

This is the error message I'm given:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[19], line 5
      3 xx = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,200)
      4 plt.plot(xx, rvweib.cdf(xx), color='orange', lw=5)
----> 5 plot_cdf(weib_variates, plot_range=[xmin, xmax], scale_to=1, lw=2, color='green')
      6 plt.axis([xmin, xmax, 0, 1])
      7 plt.title('Weibul distribution simulation', fontsize=14)

Cell In[18], line 25, in plot_cdf(data, plot_range, scale_to, **kwargs)
     23     yvalues = yvalues / len(data) * scale_to
     24 plt.axis([xmin, xmax, 0, yvalues.max()])
---> 25 return plt.plot(xvalues, yvalues, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:3794, in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   3786 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot)
   3787 def plot(
   3788     *args: float | ArrayLike | str,
   (...)
   3792     **kwargs,
   3793 ) -> list[Line2D]:
-> 3794     return gca().plot(
   3795         *args,
   3796         scalex=scalex,
   3797         scaley=scaley,
   3798         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}),
   3799         **kwargs,
   3800     )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:1779, in Axes.plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1536 """
   1537 Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
   1538 
   (...)
   1776 (``'green'``) or hex strings (``'#008000'``).
   1777 """
   1778 kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1779 lines = [*self._get_lines(self, *args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1780 for line in lines:
   1781     self.add_line(line)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:296, in _process_plot_var_args.__call__(self, axes, data, *args, **kwargs)
    294     this += args[0],
    295     args = args[1:]
--> 296 yield from self._plot_args(
    297     axes, this, kwargs, ambiguous_fmt_datakey=ambiguous_fmt_datakey)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:486, in _process_plot_var_args._plot_args(self, axes, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs, ambiguous_fmt_datakey)
    483     axes.yaxis.update_units(y)
    485 if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 486     raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    487                      f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
    488 if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    489     raise ValueError(f"x and y can be no greater than 2D, but have "
    490                      f"shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (4,) and (503,)


The answer to your issue lies in the traceback. Sizes are mismatching.
Check bin_edges[:1] probably you meant bin_edges[1:].
I guess this is an exercise to prove your understanding, for usual day to day just use
plt.hist(data, bins=num_bins, density=True, cumulative=True, histtype='step')


I noticed the size mismatch but I'm not familiar enough with Python to figure out how exactly the sizes got mismatched. I tried changing this but didn't notice any difference in outcome
